# Получение html кода страницы

Tags: c#, html, post

Недавно задавал вопрос про авторизацию POST запросом, вроде разобрался, но вот есть одна проблема, получаю код страницы без информации. Есть разметка, но судя по всему не вся,  данные отсутствуют (на их месте знаки вопроса), так же отсутствует таблица с оборудованием (на месте большого белого пятна)

P.S ссылка с кодом на прошлый вопрос [Авторизация с помощью POST запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647062/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)
. Если необходимые еще какие-нибудь данные, могу прислать/добавить в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Google Chrome посмотрел какой конкретно файл подтягивает необходимую информацию и вызвал его GET запросом